# Is there any way to use jupyter notebook to run different python version in the same notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, environment

I have added the conda environment to my Jupyter notebook, but the Python version is still 3.8 (Fig 1). What I would like to do is to create an environment which contains Python version 3.7 in a Jupyter notebook without starting from a command prompt and running two separate Jupyter notebooks (Fig 2). Is it possible to have simply one jupyter notebook with two separate environments and two different Python versions?

**Fig1**

[image]

**Fig2**

[image]

Comment: I think a bit more context on *why* one would need this functionality would be helpful to understanding whether or not your issue is actually an XY problem. Would you mind elaborating on what gives rise to this requirement?

Comment: @esqew Yes, I have two different jobs. One used pakages related to Pyhon 3.7 and the other one used pakages related to Python 3.8. Since, I am new to Python, and am starting to use a jupyter notebook to run Python. I used to use Googlecolab but it could not apply to all the work that I have on hand.

Comment: @tassaneel it's good for you that it works. But you should just downgrade one of your packages to the point where both support the same python version. That's also good for production.

Comment: This answers my question more precisely. : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro9l0eapoJU).

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this page of the docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) for ipykernel.

In your environment you want to install *only* ipykernel (not full Jupyter), and use one of the `ipykernel install --name` command to register the kernels with Jupyter.

If that does not work, use `jupyter kernelspec list` to see which kernels jupyter see and where. A kernelspec is at minimum a `kernel.json` file in the right place to tell jupyter how to find kernels.

For example I have the following

```
$ cat ~/miniconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "~/miniconda3/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

I can use the documentation above, or create the following by hand:

```
$ cat ~/miniconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3.6/kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "~/miniconda3/envs/mypython36env/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3.6 !!",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

and assuming I have the corresponding Python 3.6 env, then I'll get two kernel one of them being Python 3.6